# EF trying to map SqlGeography instead of DbGeography when using ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, entity-framework, geography, sqlgeography

Why the Entity Framework binds the same field of Geography type with two different types (SqlGeography and DbGeography) based on way of retrieving data?

I recieve an exception when trying to read data by ExecuteReader

> The specified cast from a materialized 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography' type to the 'System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography' type is not valid.

Here is a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [OneGeoField]([Position] [geography] NOT NULL
```

And data:

```
INSERT INTO OneGeoField (Position) VALUES(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (30.5047009495918 59.862826902743)',4326))
```

EF generates a class for this table with DbGeography type of Position field:

```
public partial class OneGeoField
{
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography Position { get; set; }
}
```

When retrieving data with **SqlQuery** method it works fine

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM OneGeoField";    
var list = db.Database.SqlQuery<OneGeoField>(query).ToList();
```

But in case of using **ExecuteReader**, it throws an exception

```
        try
        {
            var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            db.Database.Connection.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
            var list = objectContext.Translate<Core.OneGeoField>(reader).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
```

Is it only solution to have a different model for ExecuteReader, and another for common approach?